WSL is slow for redirecting input and output to file in VSCode
I am trying to run a c++ file, redirecting the input and output in VSCode:
~/cp/bin/test.exe < ~/cp/io/in.txt > ~/cp/io/out.txt

It is painstakingly slow when I keep the in.txt and out.txt tabs open on VSCode.
It turns out that when I first close out.txt, run the command, then reopen out.txt, the code's new output is shown.
It's also worth noting that using the terminal for I/O is fast, and timing the above command is around 0.001s, so I believe it's a VSCode issue.
I have searched the internet, and found something related to stdbuf -o0 -i0 -e0, but does not resolve this issue.
When using native windows, the equivalent command above nearly instantly applies the above changes.
I am wondering if anyone else has reported this issue?

Why do you ask this here, instead of here : Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer

@PepijnKramer because it isn't a VSCode problem? For future people reading with the same problem, it turns out that I wasn't even connected to the WSL remote server, a stupid overlook on my part.

If you found what the issue is maybe you should mention it here, so we can all learn from it (at least I am curious what the issue was) ;)
